# Firebase event parameter logging suddenly dropping to zero

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I noticed the Firebase Analytics console stopped reporting correct numbers when filtering by parameters:

[image: Drop in parameter reporting from 5~ million to zero]

As you can see the parameter drops significantly from 5~ million events a day to zero.

If we don't filter by event parameter it shows the correct numbers:

[image: Parameter reporting unfiltered looks fine]

This is the case with almost all analytics events logging custom parameters. Each event started dropping to zero on a different day so for example on the 14th of April "PopupView" event started reporting zero for all parameters while "Game" event started reporting zero for all parameters on the 3rd of May.

At the same time, some parameters have not yet started dropping to zero. For example: the PlayersType parameter on the "Game" event.

My question is has something changed with Firebase Analytics? Has something been deprecated or moved?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please file a ticket here https://firebase.google.com/support.

Comment: seeing the same.  Did you happen to get an answer?

Comment: I filed a ticket. Will update with any info here.

Comment: No information yet. The Firebase support team are checking it out.

Comment: "We continue to discuss this internally. Hopefully will be addressed on a next release soon, but at the moment we have no ETA for resolution. For future updates, please check our release notes. For now, I'll close out this ticket." This is really getting on my nerves. If anyone else is experiencing this bug it would help if you can link to this issue (Firebase support case: Case 00067522).